# For Loop in Mail Merge

Tags: loops, conditional-statements, mailmerge

How may I accomplish something like this in mail merge?

```
for i in count where count is 4
    if applicant<i>.category = 'Main'
        applicant<i>.organisationname applicant<i>.firstname applicant<i>.surname
        break
```

These are my mail merge fields:

```
«Applicant1_OrganisationName» «Applicant1_FirstName» «Applicant1_Surname»
«Applicant2_OrganisationName» «Applicant2_FirstName» «Applicant2_Surname»
«Applicant3_OrganisationName» «Applicant3_FirstName» «Applicant3_Surname»
«Applicant4_OrganisationName» «Applicant4_FirstName» «Applicant4_Surname»
```

Is there a way to do a for-loop and conditional checking in the mail merge? I have [this](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MailMerge/MMergeIfFields.htm) for reference but it doesn't have looping, I think.